# Renpy - the preceding tag statement does not expect a block. Please check this line's indentation

Tags: python, renpy

Trying to port a pre-developed game to Android Build using Renpy. However, it always throws the error:

File "game/radioactive/getlucky/screen/GetLuckyScreen.rpy", line 10: Line is indented, but the preceding tag statement does not expect a block. Please check this line's indentation.
    vbox:

```html
  
init python:
    store.DarkGold = "#6F611F"
    style.gl_text.xalign = 1.0
    style.gl_text.yalign = 0.5
    style.gl_text.color = store.DarkGold



screen GetLuckyScreen() tag menu:
    use navigation #line 10

    
    vbox:
        style_group "gl"
        xfill True
        frame background DarkGold xfill True yalign 0.5 padding(2,2) ysize 300:
            frame background "#BAA235" xfill True yalign 0.5 yfill True:
                grid 2 1 xalign 0.31 yalign 0.1:
```

Comment: Could you paste some of the contents of `GetLuckyScreen.rpy`? Especially the lines before and after line 10.

Comment: there you go. Added the code @Brian

Comment: Which line is the 10th line? You may add a comment at the end of the line using `#`.

Comment: added. now please check@Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with renpy. But according to this [document](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/screen_special.html), and my research. I guess your code should be modified as this:

```
init python:
    store.DarkGold = "#6F611F"
    style.gl_text.xalign = 1.0
    style.gl_text.yalign = 0.5
    style.gl_text.color = store.DarkGold



screen GetLuckyScreen():

    tag menu

    use navigation #line 10


    vbox:
        style_group "gl"
        xfill True
        frame background DarkGold xfill True yalign 0.5 padding(2,2) ysize 300:
            frame background "#BAA235" xfill True yalign 0.5 yfill True:
                grid 2 1 xalign 0.31 yalign 0.1:
```

I moved `tag menu` to the next line and indented it with 4 spaces.